# How does one make sense of $\mathrm{F}^{\infty}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\mathrm{F}^{n}$ is defined as a set of lists with length n, but by definition a length of a list must be a finite non-negative integer. If that is the case then how do I make sense of the objects in $\mathrm{F}^{\infty}$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Technically $F^\infty$ has nothing to do with $F^n$. And your book gives an absolutely precise definition of the space $F^\infty$. So what's your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\in \Bbb N$, any element $x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ of $\mathbf{F}^n$ can be identified with a function $f_x: \{1,2,\ldots, n\} \to \mathbf{F}$ in the obvious way, i.e., define $f_x(i) = x_i$ for each $1\le i\le n$. The domain of the function $f_x$ is often called the *indexing set* since the elements of the domain $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ correspond to the subscripts in $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

The space $\mathbf{F}^\infty$ is just a generalization of this notion, where you allow the *indexing set* to be infinite, namely $\Bbb N$. It's easy to see that for every function $f_x: \Bbb N \to \mathbf{F}$, we can associate a sequence $x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots) = \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in the obvious way, i.e., define $x_i := f_x(i)$ for each $i\in \Bbb N$ (and vice-versa.)

With that in mind, you can generalize even further if you wish, by allowing *arbitrary* indexing sets $\Lambda$ and considering functions $f: \Lambda \to \mathbf{F}$.